# Why do I need 2 reputation to post on Meta SE?

Tags: discussion, support, privileges

I have recently joined Meta SE to find that I cannot write questions, or post answers and therefore can't earn the reputation to start earning reputation.

I understand that there is a 100 reputation bonus across all sites when you reach trusted user.

The reputation limit for writing Questions and Answers is **2** whereas I start with only **1**.

Comment: Because a whole flood of people click on the MSE links in the right sidebar, and ask questions thinking that they're on SO still.

Comment: So how can I post a legitimate question? Do I need to become a trusted user?

Comment: See [Sudden increase in off-topic posts on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278562/sudden-increase-in-off-topic-posts-on-mse)

Comment: Also, I know this is a side issue, but why do I then need 5 rep. to participate in meta?

Comment: Isn't it 6 anymore? Ah, well,, the question is about Meta **SE**.

Comment: Also, we *had* decreased it back down to 1 for a 24-hour test period a few days ago to see if the off-topic question wave had subsided. It hadn't.

Comment: Make a (*useful*) suggested edit to some post to jumpstart your rep. Clean up some grammar or spelling, say.

Comment: @animuson: Mind sticking that in comments over there, by the way?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I mean on the Meta SE privileges. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges) it says that, to participate in meta meta, I need 5 reputation.

Comment: @wizzwizz2 that's because they're the standard privileges for all sites and there's no meta for meta SE because it's a meta site already.

Comment: @wizzwizz2 It also says you can post questions and answers [with a minimum reputation of 2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts).

Comment: This question is off-topic because it neither concerns the parent site nor this meta-site itself, instead being specific to the central meta-site [meta.se].

Comment: I understand, yet I couldn't post on Meta, hence the question. Is there some way to move the question?

Comment: @Deduplicator Could this be moved to Meta SE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in the comments, Meta.SE has been receiving a lot of traffic due to the sidebar, especially considering how small they are in relation to Stack Overflow.

Unfortunately, there were a number of 1 rep users that didn't realize that they weren't on SO anymore. And they were drowning out the legitimate posts with their programming questions. It was a pain for the community and its moderators to deal with.

To stop this, they raised the bar to 2 rep to post a question/answer (MSE is its own site, meaning the bar is typically just 1 rep to post). You can easily gain 2 rep by just suggesting an edit. Be sure that the edit is good; I suggest that you search for "dont" or "ive", pick one post, and correct all the spelling/grammar mistakes.

See [Sudden increase in off-topic posts on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278562/) for more details.